# TextField text not being added to mutable array

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, nsmutablearray

I am using textfield for the user to enter his username and password to signup and then store it in an array. But when i log my array it shows null. This is my code

```
    User = self.Username.text;
    UserPassword = self.UserPass.text;
    LoginPageViewController *loginPage;
    [loginPage.registeredUsernames addObject:User];
    [loginPage.registeredPassword addObject:UserPassword];
    NSLog(@"%@", loginPage.registeredUsernames);
    NSLog(@"%@", loginPage.registeredPassword);
```

Please help

Comment: How did you instantiate `loginPage.registeredUsernames` and `loginPage.registeredPassword`? `Null` probably mean your arrays are `nil` because you haven't instantiated them.

Comment: i did it in another .m file

Comment: As the others say, you haven't instantiated `loginPage`. Try doing that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

loginPage is a variable only declared, but is not instanciated any object.
 This means that is nil, we you send the message loginPage.registeredUsernames nothing happens because no object exist to handle that message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialise your mutable array? If not try initialise the array and save the direct values in array like,

```
[loginPage.registeredUsernames addObject:self.Username.text];
[loginPage.registeredPassword addObject:self.UserPass.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not instantiated your object. Try this code :

```
User = self.Username.text;
UserPassword = self.UserPass.text;
NSMutableArray *arrayUsernames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrayPasswords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
LoginPageViewController *loginPage = [[LoginPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginPageViewController" bundle:nil];
[arrayUsernames addObject:User];
[arrayPasswords addObject:UserPassword];
loginPage.registeredUsernames = arrayUsernames;    
loginPage.registeredPassword = arrayPasswords;
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that your `LoginPageViewController` object's properties `registeredUsernames` and `registeredPassword` are NSMutableArrays.

If that is indeed the case, given you code, you will need to instantiate the `LoginPageViewController *loginPage` and make sure that in the `init` method for this object you are properly instantiating the `registeredUsernames` and `registeredPassword` properties. Something to the effect of:

```
...
_registeredUsernames = [NSMutableArray new];
_registeredPassword  = [NSMutableArray new];
...
```

Note that the code you posted is not initializing the `loginPage` object, perhaps that is a typo in the post, otherwise you will need to initialize the object before using it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm... could you post the code related to the initialization of `LoginPageViewController` where you are initializing the `registeredUserNames` and `registeredUserPassword` properties?

Answer (score 0):

First initiate LoginPageViewControllers object and  registeredUsernames,registeredPassword array then directly pass your textfield value  to array. Try this code

```
LoginPageViewController*loginPage = [[LoginPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginPageViewController" bundle:nil];
  loginPage.registeredUsernames=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  loginPage.registeredPassword=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


 [loginPage.registeredUsernames addObject:self.Username.text];
 [loginPage.registeredPassword addObject:self.UserPass.text];
 NSLog(@"%@", loginPage.registeredUsernames);
 NSLog(@"%@", loginPage.registeredPassword);
```